# Image Deconvolution Using FFT

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to blind unblur an image using a gauss filter using the following code
but I know I've a problem whenever the filter contains zero, so I wonder if there is any other method of deconvolution but using the FFT

```
function [ out ] = imblur( file)

img = im2double(imread(file));

h = fspecial('gaussian', [15 15], 3);

img_red = img(:,:,1);
img_blue = img(:,:,2);
img_green = img(:,:,3);


[m,n] = size(img_red);
[mb,nb] = size(h);

% output size 
mm = m + mb - 1;
nn = n + nb - 1;

x1(:,:,1) = (ifft2(fft2(img_red,mm,nn)./ fft2(h,mm,nn)));
x2(:,:,2) = (ifft2(fft2(img_blue,mm,nn)./ fft2(h,mm,nn)));
x3(:,:,3) = (ifft2(fft2(img_green,mm,nn)./ fft2(h,mm,nn)));

out = cat(3, x1(:,:,1), x2(:,:,2), x3(:,:,3)); 

imshow(out);
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/deconvblind.html

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how is it implemented using the FFT

Comment: I think you are doing it right. Just dont bother with specifying output size. an fft function's output will always give u the same size as the input signal because it implements a DFT actually. Also, you might need to divide the ifft result by the length of the signal(not sure if MATLAB does that automatically).

Comment: @Kishore after transforming the filter with FFT some of the entries are zeros, I think this method is flawed.

Comment: oh wait, I think you are getting problems when the array contains zeros because you are dividing by zero. For this, this link provides some directions: http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/101760

Comment: I would suspect `deconvblind` uses FFT, did you check its source already ? toolbox/images/deconvblind.m

Comment: In http://jstarck.free.fr/Blind07.pdf they mention that Tikhonov regularization can be done in Fourier space by adding a term in the denominator (hence avoiding divisions by zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing the zeros with epsilon worked just fine.